# OCaml: Why does this compile when the variable is not defined?

Tags: ocaml

In studying OCaml I found this bit of code that I was sure would throw an exception, but instead it returned the value 1.

```
  let x = 1 in 
  let f y = x in 
  let x = 2 in 
  f 0;;
```

If I think of it sequentially, ok, `x` takes the value one.  Then in the lower context, we say `f y = x`.  Since `y` isn't defined, I would think right here the compiler should throw an exception.  Even if `y` were defined, I'd think this would perhaps "define `f` at `y`" if it acts kidn of like Haskell.  But I would not expect it to define `f` for other values.

So I seem to be a little confused about how this is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in OCaml don't change value, they are immutable. Your code defines two *different* things named `x`. The function `f` uses the first definition always. When you define a new value with the same name, this has no effect on `f`.

When you say `let f y = x` you are *defining* `y`, not referring to a previous `y`. You're giving the name `y` to the parameter of `f`, which can then be used in the definition of `f` (though your code chooses not to use `y`, which is perfectly fine).

Comment: Oh, so if I understand this right, that line basically say "`f` on any input will be `x` (which is 1)."